# Batch code is not going to label

Tags: batch-file

I wrote a .bat script but the end of the script doesn´t work it doesn´t del the stuff in Zukoppieren

```
echo Schreibe 
echo [L]
echo um die verbliebenen Dateien im Zukoppieren-Ordner zu loeschen

set /p %STH%=
if /i %STH%==L goto 2


:2
cd %userprofile%\desktop\Zukoppieren
for %%A in (*.*) do del %%A
```

Comment: How do you know it's not goto-ing to 2?

Answer (score 0):

When using [`set`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754250.aspx) in `cmd`, you only specify the *name* of the variable, not the `%` character:

```
set /p STH=
if /i %STH%==L goto 2
echo exiting
goto :eof
```

Comment: I added an exit section so it doesn't fall through to the delete code anyway

Answer (score 0):

With a subroutine you need to exit the code if the goto isn't executed.

This adds a different way to delete the files that is safer, and also caters for a username with a space etc in it by surrounding the term in double quotes.

The fix already mentioned by `Mathias R. Jessen` is included - using the actual variable name in the set /p command.

The set command above that resets the variable - so any previous input in the same command window will not be remembered.

The compare in the `if` command has double quotes too, so that invalid input will not cause the batch file to error and abort - if you press `enter` without typing anything for example.

```
echo Schreibe 
echo [L]
echo um die verbliebenen Dateien im Zukoppieren-Ordner zu loeschen

set "sth="
set /p STH=
if /i "%STH%"=="L" goto 2
echo quitting
goto :eof

:2
del "%userprofile%\desktop\Zukoppieren\*.*?"
```